# Struggling to replace Font Awesome Icon with my logo in template

Tags: css, html, html-table

I'm making a site from an html5up template, and there is a part of the html that has a diamond icon class in a span that I would like to change with my png logo.

The diamond icon is not in the pictures folder nor the css so I'm not sure how I would effectively replace the image in the circle? Its as follows:

```
<div class="logo"> <span class="icon fa-diamond"> </span> </div>
```

Just wondering in which folder I would place my image, would it be the SASS code? Java?

If you need anymore information let me know.

Answer (score 2):

This icon is not a image. This is font named: Font awesome. If you want to replace this icon just remove this class from span and add your img by

```html
 <span class="logo"> <img class="logo__img" src="/img/yourimg.img" alt="this is your image"><span/>
```

Look at your template default style.css file and check class="icon fa-diamond" styles and copy it to your img.png, but be sure that you change the font-size style to height of your image.

```css
.logo {
/* replace this value to a value from Font Awesome icon style*/
width: 2rem; 
height: 2rem;
}
.logo__img {
display: block;
width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Add img to main img folder. If you still had problem to replace font awesome icon to your img logo, let me know I will try to find the way out.